# How to read a string array from external file in Roboium

Tags: android, robotium

Can Any one help me how to read an array from external file in Robotium, to parameterize  the test project.
How Can I export the result in Robotium.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.array.login_arr)); List<String> list = new ArrayList<String-Arrays>(R.array.);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
String data = (scanner.next()); //read data record 
String [] values = data.split(","); 
for(int i;i<=values.length;i++){
solo.enterText(0, values[i]); 
}
```

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.array.login_arr));  
       
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String-Arrays>(R.array.); 
 
       while (scanner.hasNext()) {
       String data = (scanner.next());                  //read data record
       String [] values = data.split(",");
                solo.enterText(0, values[i]);

Comment: please post this code in your question not as comment.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "Can I export the result in Robotium." could you explain further?

Comment: Hi @Paul Harris,   After automating the test scripts I want the result as a document or a text file to send to client or to my managers.